# Any strategy tips for Tekken 1?

Tags: tekken

As a next step in my recent retro-revival adventure I picked up Tekken 1. I've never played it before because I've never owned a Playstation and I'm currently playing it on PC using an emulator and USB pad controllers.

I took some time to learn the moves for Kazuya (decided to focus on one character and he looked cool) but the problem is I'm getting my ass handed to me on easy most of the time on the later stages. The computer characters storm me and I don't have a chance to hit them back. One problem I'm having is King, he runs at me as I'm on the ground, and keeps doing body slams on me while I'm lying down. I keep mashing the dpad to get up but somehow the computer does it much quicker than I can. He also has this move where he keeps kicking low in a combo which I can't interrupt or block and which stuns me if it connects so he can do it again and keep it up forever.

I got as far as Lee, but I've never won a single round against him. He keeps kicking at me in an infinite combo, which I can block, but every now and then one of these kicks is low and gets through the block.

The other problem I'm having is that it's very difficult for me to do the special moves, I can pull them off about every 1 in 10 times. Unless I time it exactly right (not too fast, not too slow), the move doesn't work. Is it supposed to be like this?

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some practice, I managed to beat the game on Ultra Hard with 5 rounds. I'm posting an answer with my own tips.

The game isn't much harder on Ultra Hard than it is on Easy, except on Easy the first few characters are really easy, but the later ones kick ass Ultra-Hard-style anyway.

I'll be focusing on Kazuya since he's the one I've got figured out.

- When the AI is far away it will run at you with a jump/pounce attack, when it's close, it will start a barrage of combos. When at medium distance, it just stands around unsure what to do. If you are too close, jump back (holding back will also take care of blocking in case the AI launches a combo), then quickly close in and do an uppercut/dragon punch. Follow with another, or a forward jump kick to juggle the AI.
- Learning to run is very important. Storm the AI as it storms you. When it's on the ground, run in close and do a sweep, which will throw it away and on the ground again. Then run again and do a jump kick. Repeat alternating between sweeps and jump kicks.
- A good way to open a fight is to jump in and do a throw. If successful, run in, sweep, jump kick, run in...
- At later stages, it's no use doing pounces on the AI when it's on the ground, because it always gets up almost immediately and will block the pounce and hit you.
- A useful move is the forward jump kick, especially at close range when the AI is momentarily immobile after you'd blocked a combo. You land near it, and can immediately follow with a sweep, run in, jump-kick...
- The game has no practice mode, but a 5-round two-player game with infinite time is almost as good.

The game is rather difficult and unpredictable even at Easy, nothing to be done about it, some fights you won't be able to get a hit in, especially if the AI manages to hit first, then keeps running in and hitting you as you lie down or are in the middle of getting up. Strangely enough, getting up takes a long time sometimes for you, but not the AI.

Answer (score 0):

Some basic tips on Tekken:

- To block a high or mid hit, stand still. To block a low hit, crouch.
- When you go down, press up/down to roll sideways character wise or left/right to roll sideways camera wise. Press any kick key (not sure if punches work) to get up with an attack.
- Some attacks can't be blocked, but you can dodge them by jumping.
- If you are having trouble beating a certain opponent, try playing that character for a bit, to get a feel of how he reacts and what his moves are.
- There is a practice mode, use it to master the timing on combos.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to roll character-wise in Tekken 1. I've seen Heihachi step into the camera sometimes but AFAIK he's the only one that can do it. There also isn't a practice mode.